# php stream_copy_to_stream()/fwrite() "resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: php, smtp

Now before you send me off to Google where I've spent plenty of time on this issue...

Here's the scenario:

**Client**: SMTP server sending email with 1MB attachment

**Middle man**: PHP proxy script (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134880/simple-tcp-proxy)

**Destination**: PHP script accepting and processing SMTP connection/commands

What happens is, the Client sends SMTP data up until the "DATA" command, which the Destination accepts without any error from the Proxy. During the "DATA" command, when the Client is delivering mail data, this happpens:

`PHP Notice:  stream_copy_to_stream(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=11 Resource temporarily unavailable in /root/proxy.php on line 59`
 (this occurs on the Proxy script)

line 59 reffered to in the Notice above:

`stream_copy_to_stream($client, $dest)` (with `$client` referring to Client SMTP server and `$dest` referring to Destination PHP script)

I *think* that this is in regards to the Client attempting to write data to  Destination as Destination is busy, but what could it be busy with? Is the Destination still reading data from the stream from Proxy when Client is attempting to write to it? Would that cause this error? What exactly is happening?

If any code is required besides the Proxy code above, please let me know and I'll update this post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself after rigorous testing. With the way the code was set up, there was only one `stream_select()` function blocking and waiting for the `$client` stream to have data available for **reading**. The problem is I didn't include a second `stream_select()` to block until the destination stream was writable.

In essence, the following code works 100%:

```
--- snip ---

stream_select($r_sockets, $w = NULL, $e = NULL, NULL);
stream_select($r = NULL, $w_sockets, $e = NULL, NULL);

in_array($client, $r_sockets) && in_array($dest, $w_sockets) ?
    stream_copy_to_stream($client, $dest, 1024):
    stream_copy_to_stream($dest, $client, 1024);
```

The `1024` as the 3rd parameter to `stream_copy_to_stream()` is what allowed the data to flow at a stable pace, instead of copying too much data from the `$client` to the `$dest` and causing the error.